# How to completely restore Unity Launcher (all icons are missing)? Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: unity, icons, crash

I was a little too brave in Terminal (manual "sudo rm -rf name_of_icons/themes" cleaning) and it seems I broke Unity.
At first I did see some icons in left-pane, but after using command `unity --reset-icons` all the icons are missed. After entering and confirming this command I got a bunch of errors-related reports of "something" missing (I really didn't remember all of it).
And if I click on the Launcher upper-left button, Ubuntu freezes.

So, the question is, how to restore Ubuntu Unity? If possible, without using any other settings. Via terminal, maybe with Ubuntu on my DVD?

Thanks in advance!

/////

A few hours later I installed mate-environment-desktop-core via terminal. So I logged in in MATE and saw that there are also some icons missing. There, where they should be, is just a grey square. So maybe a problem is deepest? What do you suggest?

Br.

Comment: If you do a `locate /usr/share/themes | grep --ignore-case .png | wc` and a `locate /usr/share/unity/themes | grep --ignore-case .png | wc` what's the output?

Comment: The result is [link](http://shrani.si/f/3d/s0/256AyBny/20141201015345richtonehd.jpg) I had to use (left)ALT+F2 and login to enter commands.

Comment: If needed, I can make a photo of my desktop. (Why can't I edit my previous comment?)

Comment: That is the same as I have, so that is good.  Do you remember where exactly you deleted the themes?

Comment: Themes and packs of icons were deleted from '/usr/share/themes' and [code]/usr/share/icons[/code]. I can't say for sure, but icons were maybe also deleted from [code]~/.icons[/code]. I wanted to delete all except default ones. Btw, at the moment I'm logged as a guest and everything is ok. No theme neither icons are missing in guest session.

Comment: So in the guest session everything is OK???  How about you log in into the console using [Ctrl][Alt][F1], create an additional user (slashme2) and logging into that one using the UI?  What does that do???

Comment: Hi, I did create a new user (via terminal) and logged in with it. Everything is ok - background, windows, cursor and icons are in the shape as needed. ----- So obviously something is wrong just with my primary user account.

Comment: Btw, I have a topic opened also on the Ubuntu Forums. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2254775 Someone asked me if I have a 'local' folder in 'home' directory. Here is a printscreen: http://shrani.si/f/2q/MX/ViQY2Gu/2014-12-02-020617.jpg

Comment: You did an `rm -rf` and have a icons dissapearing but both are unrelated to each other.  Look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

As a secondary user does not exhibit the behaviour of your primary user, there is something else wrong in your primary user's profile.

Therefore, you can look and look and look and eventually find *what* is wrong, but I would not worry and just copy (**not move: copy**) all your Documents, Downloads, ... from the "problem" user to the new user and then delete these from the bad user.

E.G.:

```
sudo cp --recursive --force /home/slashme/Documents /home/slashme2/Documents
```

if no errors:

```
sudo rm -r /home/slashme/Documents
```

repeat for bin, Pictures, Templates, Desktop, Downloads, Music, Public, Videos

then delete user "slashme", rename "slashme2" to "slashme" and forget this ever happened.

## Problem solved!

(and be more careful in the future, take a system backup first!)

P.S. If this problem *ever* resurfaces (which I doubt), re-open this problem and then we'll dig down (with more foreknowledge) again!  :-)